# Write to GCS using TextIO.write() from postgres with header

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am having a pipeline be run on GCP Dataflow where I read from an SQL instance and collect the data in a PCollection and then write that PCollection to a CSV file. It seems that while writing to CSV I cannot pass the header at Runtime (as a valueprovider) as given [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.40.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Write.html#withHeader-java.lang.String-) the header has to be a string argument.

I have tried giving an empty string and updating the string in runtime, but it doesn't work. I take the first empty string as header only.

Is there any way that I can generate the header inside and have that string as header or if I can pass the header as a runtime argument?

Attaching the textio code below

```
String header = /*header*/;
PCollection<String> output = /*jdbc result*/;

output
    .apply(
        "Write File(s)",
        TextIO.write()
            .to(options.getFilePath())
            .withSuffix(".csv")
            .withHeader(header)
            .withShardNameTemplate("-S-of-N")
            .withTempDirectory(options.getTempDirectory()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the problem, I think you can pass a program argument as String :

```
--header=test
```

Options in `Java` code :

```java
public interface MyOptions extends PipelineOptions {

    @Description("Header")
    String getHeader();

    void setHeader(String value);
}
```

Then pass it in the `withHeader(header)` method :

```java
output
    .apply(
        "Write File(s)",
        TextIO.write()
            .to(options.getFilePath())
            .withSuffix(".csv")
            .withHeader(options.getHeader())
            .withShardNameTemplate("-S-of-N")
            .withTempDirectory(options.getTempDirectory()))
```

If you want, you can also configure the `header` outside in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Currently `withHeader` is an argument that has to be specified at construction time, so it cannot be provided using `PCollection` element values.

You might be able to do this by breaking your pipeline into two pipelines, or generating/discovering the header value within your program from where the Beam pipeline is started.